# SGE: threads per slot -pe smp

Tags: sungridengine

I run a job using 4 slots with -pe smp. I only use one thread per slot, even though the thread only consumes about 33% of available memory. Can I increase the number of threads or won't it make any difference? The job doesn't have too much I/O....

Comment: Please clarify.  Is the program you're running capable of using multiple threads?  How many instances of this program do you need to run concurrently?  How many CPUs are available on each server in the cluster?

Comment: So, you are using 4 threads, each consuming 33% of memory, totaling 132% of total memory?